# Assigning shortcut keys for adding code templates in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ide, development-environment, code-reuse

This might be a silly question, but I've started learning Xcode and one thing came to my mind today.

That is, some codes are reused again and again throughout the project.

For example, for debugging purpose you can put `NSLog(@"error!");` in many different places.

Is it possible at all to assign some shortcut keys for adding these "template" codes in `Xcode`, so that whenever you need to add a template, you can just hit the corresponding shortcut key?

I have tried to google it, but I didn't get lucky.

This might be a trivial function or even an unnecessary one, but if it is possible to hit just one combination of keys instead of typing a line of code, I think it will help improving the speed of coding.

Any ideas? If not in `Xcode`, does any other IDE provide this function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can!

[image]

Setting it up is slightly non-intuitive, but here is how you can do it.

1. Type the code you want to templatize.
2. In the right-side bar, select the Code Snippet Library option in the horizontal toolbar halfway down the bar (which has the `{}` icon).
3. Select your code and drag it to the Code Snippet Library.

Refer to the image above.  Anything you want to be replacable, enclose in `<# whatever #>`.

In this screen shot above, I have set the shortcut to <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, and the replacable text is `<# protocol #>`.

Now, when I type the shortcut, I see:

[image]

And hitting tab completes to this:

[image]

You can make them arbitrarily complex.  For example, here is a multi-line snippet that I use to outline a view when debugging `UIView` hierarchy or layout issue:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! `Select your code and drag it to the Code Snippet Library.` How do I "drag" the code?

Comment: Oh, I found the solution. You can hold your mouse for a moment, then you will be able to drag the code. Thanks.